# jQuery - How to cancel form submit prevent default when condition is true

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a contact form that I check the input values when clicking on the submit button, if there's at least one input empty, I run an alert and preventDefault the form submition, else, I return true.

My issue here is that when I deliberately omit an input, I get what I want, but then if I fill all the inputs, I can't submit the form any more...

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery('#envoyez').on('click', function () {
            jQuery(':input').each(function () {
                const val = jQuery.trim(jQuery(this).val());
                if (val.length == 0) {
        alert('Fill all the inputs please');
                     jQuery("form").submit(function(e){
                     e.preventDefault();
                         });
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            })
        })
    })
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should declare the form event listener in your `.ready()` function. Then create a variable that handles validity of the form.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    // count the number of inputs that are filled.
    var clearCount = 0;

    jQuery("form").submit(function(e) {

        // here check if clearcount is not equal to the number of fields
        if (clearCount != jQuery(':input').length)
        {
            // this means that one of the fields are not filled
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    });

    jQuery('#envoyez').on('click', function () {

      // reset clearcount for revalidation
      clearCount = 0;

      jQuery(':input').each(function () {
          const val = jQuery.trim(jQuery(this).val());
          // check if input is not empty.
          if (val.length > 0) {
              clearCount++;
          }
      })
  })

});
```

This is just a simple approach of fixing your problem though if you want a way more better method you could just simply:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    jQuery("form").submit(function(e) {

        // check if one of the fields are empty
        // and so on
        if (   jQuery(this).find("input[name='NAME1']").val().length == 0
            || jQuery(this).find("input[name='NAME2]").val().length == 0
            || jQuery(this).find("input[name='NAME3']").val().length == 0)
        {
            // this means that one of the fields are not filled
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```js
$("#myForm").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    //Check for any blank fields. Return true or false
    var isBlankInput = $("#myForm input").filter(function(){return $.trim($(this).val()).length === 0}).length === 0; 
    
    if (!isBlankInput) {
        alert('Fill all the inputs please');
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Form submission");
        //$(this).submit();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm">
    <input type="text" value="" />
    <input type="text" value="" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Form" />
</form>
```