# HTML JS - Bootstrap Form Validate

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I have a simple Model that appears that allows the user to fill in some informations. However, I would like to have a validation process;

```
<form class="form-default" role="form" id="MyForm" action="form.php" method="POST">

            <label class="control-label text-uppercase">Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="name">
            <div class="alert alert-danger" id="name" hidden="true">Your name is required.</div>

</form>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-styled btn-base-1" id="submitForm">Submit</button>
```

When the user submits this, its passed to a JS/Ajax function;

```
<script>
    /* must apply only after HTML has loaded */
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(“#MyForm”).on("submit", function(e) {
            var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
            var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
            //I assume I need to check here for validation first.
            $.ajax({
                url: formURL,
                type: "POST",
                data: postData,
                success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    $('#myModal .modal-body').html(data);
                    $("#closeForm").html("Finish");
                    $("#submitForm").remove();
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, status, error) {
                    console.log(status + ": " + error);
                }
            });
            e.preventDefault();
        });

        $("#submitForm").on('click', function() {
            $("#MyForm").submit();
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is passed to a PHP script that processes the form data. However, I wish to check before hand for any missing data/validate it. If so, then I need to turn the 'alert-danger div' hidden to false.

Any ideas how I can edit the $(“#MyForm”) script to handle such a task?
Thanks.

Comment: Hello kindly refer to this post [Validate form before submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46019402/jquery-how-to-cancel-form-submit-prevent-default-when-condition-is-true/46019456#46019456)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery - How to cancel form submit prevent default when condition is true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46019402/jquery-how-to-cancel-form-submit-prevent-default-when-condition-is-true)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the `onclick` event of `submitForm` button, check whether the required text field `name` has data using jQuery before calling `submit` process. If it has data `return true` or else `return false`.

```
if($("input[name='name']").val()=="") {
   return false;
}
return true;
```

`return false` will prevent the submit form process from being fired

Comment: Thank you, how do i get the '<div class="alert alert-danger">' to show upon false?

Comment: @OliverJones  Use `$("#name").show();` to show div and `$("#name").hide()` to hide div. Alternatively, you can also use `$("#name").toggle();` to toggle the hidden state.